# Python Decorators accessing scope variables

Tags: python, scope, decorator

Can Python decorators access all variables within the decorated function scope? e.g.

```
@decme
def call_me():
    ...

def caller_function():
    context = context_creator()
    call_me()
```

In this scenario, can `decme` decorator access the `context` variable?

we know that `call_me` will be able to access `context` if we pass it in as an argument, is there a way to pass `context` to `decme` function?

Please note that the call_me function could be defined in separate modules, which means that `@decme(context)` might not be ok at the time we call the `call_me` function

Comment: no, because is in the inner scope of other function. As normal functions cant acces other functions scope unless the variables there are global. The only way to retrieve the value of contex is returning it from caller_function so when the `decme` decorator executes the `caller_function` can get it

Comment: but is there a way that I could pass it in? I know that decorators could access what ever passed into the `call_me` function as an argument, but any other ways that I could make it accessible? As my understanding is that `decme` is just another wrapper function around the actual callee function, so I guess it should be within the same scope

Answer (score 2):

@Alfe has provided some special solution.

You might have knowledge of the timing between running & decorator.

However, since your purpose is not clear, based on your current code, you can try to refactor your code into this style:

```
def decme(context):
    def real_decme(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return real_decme

def call_me():
    pass

def caller_function():
    context = context_creator()
    decme(context)(call_me)()
```

In this case, `decme` can handle context. But it won't be run during decorator generating time.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the caller stack and view all the local variables in its frames.  I'm using this technique to implement my [Stack Environment in Python](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578147-stack-environment/?in=user-4182236) which does more or less this and using which, by the way, might well solve your overall issue in a more tidy fashion.

But unless you put this decently into a nice library which hides all the ugly details I'd call this an ugly hack.

How about passing this context into `call_me()`?  Then its decorator would of course receive it.

If you choose to use the StackEnv, this would be the way to formulate it:

```
from stackEnv import stackEnv

def decme(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if stackEnv.context.someValue > someOtherValue:
            doSomething()
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decme
def call_me():
    ...

def caller_function():
    stackEnv.context = context_creator()
    call_me()
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, passing the context to `call_me()` might not be ideal, I am trying to do some light footprint logging base on the function calls, that's the reason why I want to leave as less footprints as possible

Comment: Then this sounds very much like the situation which brought me to implementing the `StackEnv`.  It "appears" to pass some kind of context into the whole sub-call-tree of the current point, and its first usage was for passing verbosity information for logging.  Your decorator is no different from any called function in this aspect.

Comment: I added a code example on how to use the `StackEnv` for your case.

Answer (score 0):

A function is an object and can have attributes. You could directly pass the context as an attribute of the wrapper:

```
def decme(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        # here we can access the context passed as wrapped.context
        print("Before context:", wrapped.context) 
        cr = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("After")
        return cr
    wrapped.context = None
    return wrapped

def caller_function():
    # just pass the context
    call_me.context = context_creator()
    call_me()
```

Here the original `call_me` has no notion of a `context` attribute, but the decorated function has. The only drawback is that it is an attribute of the function and will persist across calls. In particular it will lead to unexpected results in multithreaded environments...

---

Alternatively, you could use the decorator to add one additional parameter to the function that could be passed at run time. This way would be thread safe:

```
def decme(f):
    def wrapped(context, *args, **kwargs):
        # here we can access the context
        print("Before context:", context) 
        cr = f(*args, **kwargs)    # call the underlying function
        print("After")
        return cr
    return wrapped

@decme
def call_me():
    ...


def caller_function():
    # just pass the context
    context = context_creator()
    call_me(context)
```